# On the rank of $y^2=x^3+a^2x^2-a^4x$

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

How can I prove that the rank of $y^2=x^3+a^2x^2-a^4x$ is zero where $a$ is rational and positive?

Answer (score 2):

For any $a\neq 0$ you can do a change of variables $x=a^2X$, $y=a^3Y$, which shows that your curve is isomorphic to $Y^2=X^3+X^2-X$, which is a curve of rank $0$.